Silent errors in signalR console logs without any detail
The problem is that signalR throws error in console without any description of the issue, pic below: enter image description here
And currently I have no idea what causing this issue, on localhost everything works fine. On production it throws this error without any description. Server is Ubuntu with Nginx. Messages from server is still received but not shown in: enter image description here Client is: .Net blazor 8, api is: asp .net core 8 and server is ubuntu with nginx and restricted ssl.
Api signalR configuration:
builder.Services.AddSignalR(c =>
{
    c.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
}).AddJsonProtocol(options =>
{
    options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.PayloadSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/api/v1/hubs/notification")
        .RequireAuthorization();

    endpoints.Map(
        "/",
        context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
});

Client signalR configuration:
public async Task StartSignalR()
{
    BuidSignalRConnection();
    _hubConnection.On<object>("notification", (payload) =>
    {
    });

    await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
}

private void BuidSignalRConnection()
{
    if (_hubConnection != null && _hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        _hubConnection.StopAsync();
    }

    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
       .WithUrl($"{Config.ApiUrl}/api/v1/hubs/notification", c =>
       {
           c.AccessTokenProvider = GetAccessToken;
           c.SkipNegotiation = false;
       })
       .WithAutomaticReconnect()
       .Build();
}

Tried various solutions found on internet:
Source 1
Source 2
Source 3
stackoverflow/questions/76584651/unable-to-connect-signalr-through-nginx <- identical issue like mine but it didnt helped
stackoverflow/questions/72821395/signalr-core-negotiation-causes-cors-error-with-javascript-client
overflow/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss
But the problem is still occurring and none of solutions helped
Logs api logs:
enter image description here
Nginx logs:
enter image description here
I suspect there is some problems with nginx configuration which could be issue of these errors.
P.S. testing again on localhost error occurred as well, so it seems its not related to nginx but actual configuration of server and client

You need to check your nginx  server to make sure you have enabled websocket firstly.

At first I thought issue was related to nginx, but error started to occur on localhost as well

Localhost means the application host at the nginx and you view it directly from that server right? If this is the right, you need check your nginx or linux server to make sure you have enabled websocket or else.

Localhost means I launching from development environment both server and client without linux involved
